# How can I create a site? What should I do first?

Tags: web-development

I want to create my own site but I know absolutely nothing of the coding. Could you recommend something, what would help to start? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Zill Facon, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Comment: Please see my very long comment, which I had to post as an answer. Do you know what kind of site you want? Please tell us, if so. And rephrase your question to ask us to recommend some software. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you want to get in the end. Maybe you should start from some easy website builder like 8b (https://8b.com/), Wix or Mobirise. If you want to study the coding process, I would recommend you to try something like Mobirise's Code Editor (https://mobirise.com/extensions/code-editor.html), it would let you change the code just in the project, so you would see the result. Here you can see the instruction: https://mobirise.com/how-to/make-your-own-website/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is too long for a comment.

I am going to assume here that you want to learn to build a web site from scratch, learning HTML and CSS (and, maybe later, JavaScript).

Before you put your web site onto a real server, I would recommend developing it on your local PC first. This will be quicker, since you won’t have to waste time uploading files every time you change  them. If you run Linux, or Mac, then you already have the Apache webserver, so just need to put your files in the relevant dire cry (`/www/`, IIRC).

Since more people run Windows, you need a web server. The simplest way to get one working is to install XAMPP and follow instructions.

In all cases, your server is `localhost`, rather than `xxx.com`. Just run Apache and enter localhost into your browser’s address bar.

All that you need now is your own web page, and your question is too wide to answer, which is why I wanted to post a comment. You need an IDE and there are lots of good gratis ones – GIYF. Although it looks old & clunky, Kompozer would be a good start, as it lets you change your source and see it displayed in the same IDE; it also shows the structure of your web page. More modern is Brackets IDE, which lets you change your code & see the change instantly reflected in the browser.

On any web page in almost any browser, press F12 to see the Developer Console, which will be very helpful when looking for errors and debugging.

Find yourself a simple idea, which you would like to produce, and read tutorials; you can google or search youtube; personally, I am old school & like books, which can be picked up cheaply on eBay; alternatively, Coursera, which offers online university courses at all levels, many of them free. Keep trying until you find something that suits you, otherwise you might give up. Since you might try a few possibilities, keep them free or cheap at first.

- First lean only HTML. That is the content of the page. Start with text only, or static graphics. Nothing too fancy, until you get the hang of it.
- Next, look at CSS. While HTML defines the content of the webpage, CSS defines how it is laid out – font since & colo(u)rs, etc. Keep these two separate – do not be tempted to mix them in one single file.
- At that point, you have mastered “static” web sites, where the content is static & does not change.
- If you want to make static web sites, then lean to code Java Script.
- At that point, you have a dynamic web site. Note that there are other ways to do this, I have just shown you the most common – all of the code in in the browser at the “client-side”. You could have also generated all of the code on the server-side using PHP, Node.Js, Python, etc, but it is probably easier to learn as I have suggested.
- Beyond that, the next complexity is splitting functionality between browser (client) and server, possibly with a database on the server.

This is very broad advice and it will take a while before you get to the later parts of it. By which time, you will have a better ideas of what you want to do and how to implement it, as there are always choices.

If you already have an idea for a web site, let us know.

As mentioned in comments, there are some simple site builders where you don’t need to learn HTML and CSS (or, at least, not too much). You can also look at Drupal and WordPress, both of which are extremely popular.

Welcome aboard, and good luck :-)